# Rest API ,Maximo

Tags: rest, api, maximo

I am using rest API to post data into Maximo, but I have to pass user ID and Password to get a connectivity with maximo.
My question is how can I bypass the user ID password authentication while posting data in Maximo.As we are not supposed to share credentials with the client.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: But if you bypass authentication, how are you going to stop just anyone from posting whatever? And how are you going to know who posted it?

Comment: Is the user already authenticated somehow? Is REST being called from a browser or some custom app?

Comment: Create special user just for REST API purposes.

Answer (score 2):

7.6.1.1 Work Center Admin console, create API key for user, pass API key in script.

Answer (score 2):

### **If you are using IBM Maximo version 7.6.1 (or higher) :**

You can  use API keys to enable an inbound machine-to-machine integration for an external client. API keys can be used by the REST APIs and also can be used as part of the Maximo® Integration Framework.

1. create a user for external client
2. add permition to the user
3. create API key for the user (on the API Keys subtab on the Integration tab of the Administration Work Center)

NB:  the external client can access and interact data in the Maximo system by using the API key **as an apikey query parameter or an apikey request header in REST API calls**.

for more details : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.1.1/com.ibm.mif.doc/gp_intfrmwk/c_api_keys_comp.html